# Using multiple CSS selectors for the same ArticleItem in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

The site I am scraping has an inconsistent layout. I'm currently using this but its not returning all the titles -

```
article['title'] = sel.css('p[class=title] ::text').extract()
```

I need to use this to scrape span classes also -

```
article['title'] = sel.css('span[class=newstitle] ::text').extract()
```

Is there a way to combine two css selectors in a single ArticleItem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As simple as list concatenation:

```
article['title'] = response.css("p.title ::text").extract() + \
                   response.css("span.newstitle ::text").extract()
```

Comment: an even simpler: `response.css("p.title ::text, span.newstitle ::text").extract()`