# How to use multiple and nested span CSS selectors in Scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, css-selectors

I'm dealing with a tricky CSS selector problem that involve multiple nested *span*s.

**(A)** Normally the HTML/CSS look like this:

```html
<div class="pricing">
    <strong>1 200 €</strong> 
</div>
```

**(B)** But there are also parts that look like this:

```html
<div class="pricing">
    <strong>
        <span class="promotion">
            <span class="promo-price">1 100 €</span>
        </span>
        <span class="strike">
            <span>1 200€</span>
        </span>
    </strong>
    <div class="new">New supplier</div>
</div>
```

**(C)** and like this:

```html
<div class="pricing">
    <strong>3 400 €</strong> 
    <span>/ best:  4500.00 €</span>
</div>
```

**(D)** and like this:

```html
<div class="pricing">
    <strong>4 900 €</strong> 
    <span class="netto">+ taxes</span> 
    <span>/ best:  4900.00 €</span>
</div>
```

---

Using a Scrapy CSS selector of the type:

```python
response.css("div.pricing strong ::text").extract()
# ['2 500 €', '\n    ', '\n    ', '1 100 €', '\n    ', '\n    ', '1 200€', '3 999 €',...]
```

This show that the problematic `<span ...>` of the above CSS, adds whitespace in the selector text. So I tried to ignore *both* the `strike` and `promotion` classes with various variations of using `:not()` like this:

```python
response.css("div.pricing strong:not([class*='promotion']):not([class*='strike'])::text").extract()
# <same result as above>
```

I can also get the `promo-price` *only*, with:

```python
response.css("div.pricing  .promo-price::text").extract()
# ['1 100 €']
```

---

At this point I'm at loss on how to:

- get all the (A) prices
- get all the (B) `promo-price`s (only)
- result without the introduced white space (as shown above)
- all of the above in (preferably) **one** CSS selector or line

Q: **How can I do this in the simplest possible manner?**

---

**Note:** I have already seen the similar questions:

- [Scrapy grab div with multiple classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28140421/scrapy-grab-div-with-multiple-classes)
- [Using multiple CSS selectors for the same ArticleItem in Scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25019175/using-multiple-css-selectors-for-the-same-articleitem-in-scrapy?rq=1)

But they did not offer much help in my case.

---

**UPDATE**:

I was not able to complete the task according to @boltclock's instructions and ended up with an ugly hack, like this:

```python
adPrice = aditem.css("div.pricing strong::text").extract_first().strip()
if adPrice == '':
    adPrice = aditem.css("div.pricing span.promo-price::text").extract_first()
```

So if someone has a better or more elegant solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm.

Does that `div.new` only appear after a `strong` that contains all that complexity (B), and never after a `strong` that contains just a single price (A)?

If so:

> - get all the (A) prices
> - result without the introduced white space (as shown above)

```py
response.css("div.pricing strong:only-child::text").extract()
```

Notice the omission of the space before `::text`, which ensures you only get the text that's directly in the `strong` — see the end of my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48556919/difference-between-scrapy-selectors-atext-and-a-text) for usage guidelines.

`:only-child` ensures that it doesn't match when a `div.new` is present, if its absence implies (A), so you never have to worry about (B).

> - get all the (B) `promo-price`s (only)

```py
response.css("div.pricing .promo-price::text").extract()
```

> - all of the above in (preferably) **one** CSS selector or line

At this point, it should be a simple matter of grouping the above two selectors:

```py
response.css("div.pricing strong:only-child::text, div.pricing .promo-price::text").extract()
```

If the `div.new` is unrelated, it's going to be difficult to do this with CSS selectors since there's no other way to distinguish (A) from (B). XPath on the other hand makes short work of it:

```py
response.xpath("//div[@class='pricing']/(strong[not(./span)]|descendant::span[@class='promo-price'])/text()").extract()
```

Comment: Correct. The `div.new` seem to only appear in case(B).

Comment: I tried your combo above, and it was missing quite a few items. Investigation showed that there is yet another price version **(C)**, with a *span* in it, and who knows how many more. (I've updated my post)

Comment: I now see why the best way to extract this is using the *xpath* method. However I tried your line above, but only the first part (before the `|`) works and actually get all items except the promo ones. The second part generate an error message.